# Is it true that, if $f$ is uniformly continuous in $(a,b),$ then the limits $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function in $(a,b)$.

> I know that:
> If the limits $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ exist, then $f$ is uniformly continuous in $(a,b)$.

Is the inverse also true?

Comment: You should show your progress.

Comment: Yes. You define a continuous function at the compact $[a,b]$ by putting $ f(a)=f(a^+)$ and $ f(b)=f(b^-)$ and Heine's Theorem.

Comment: Yes but is not is the same solution for the other direction? @hamam_Abdallah what do you mean by $a^+$..

Comment: $ f(a^+)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ which exists.

Comment: The new function g is defined to be f in (a,b) and the given limits in x=a and x=b? So g is continuos in [a,b], so by cantor theorem g is uniformly continuos in [a,b] thus g is uniformly continuos in (a,b) where f=g? @hamam_Abdallah is that right?

Comment: Yes. For me, it's Heine Theorem, not Cantor.

Comment: Sorry! I was not on focus, i meant the other direction..i edited my question @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: @Bestmat Please don't materially change your question after you receive a legitimate answer.  It just causes confusion.  Much better would be to ask another question with the corrected form.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Hint for the other direction.  Cauchy criterion.

Comment: I don't see how to use Cauchy..@GEdgar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES.

If we define
$$
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) & \text{if} & x=a, \\
f(x) & \text{if} & x\in (a,b), \\
\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x) & \text{if} & x=b.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
then $g$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, and hence uniformly continuous.
Consequently, so is
$$
f=g|_{(a,b)}
$$

INVERSE. *If $f: (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then the limits
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)
$$
exist.*

Proof. We need the following:

Lemma. *If $f$ uniformly continuous and $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then so is $\{f(a_n)\}$.*

Assuming the above, let $x_n\to a$, then $\{f(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy and hence convergent. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\ell$. We shall show that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\ell$. If not, then there would be an $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $\{y_n\}\subset (a,b)$, such that $y_n\to a$ and $|f(y_n)-\ell|\ge \varepsilon$. Let $\{z_n\}$ be the sequence
$$
z_1=x_1,\, z_2=y_1,\, z_3=x_2,\,z_4=y_2,\,z_5=x_3,\,z_6=y_3,\,
\text{etc},
$$
then $z_n\to a$, hence $\{f(z_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $f(z_{2n-1})=f(x_n)\to\ell$, then $f(z_n)\to\ell$,
and thus $f(z_{2n})=f(y_n)\to\ell$, contradiction.

**Note.** More generally, if $A\subset\mathbb R$ and $f: A\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $A$, then the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists for every $a\in \overline{A}$, and $f$ extends continuously on $\overline{A}$.

Comment: Sorry! I was not on focus, i meant the other direction..i edited my question @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis

Comment: @Bestmat You should edit the title, too.

Comment: @Bestmat See the improved version of my answer,

Comment: @Bestmat Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you! In the same way we show that $lim_{x\to b^-} f(x) exist$ right? And in your symbols you used a in (a,b) and a as a limi @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis

Answer (score 0):

Today I also have the same doubts, But I think we say the inverse of the given statement only holds when a and b are finite, otherwise, I have a counterexample $f: R \to R   $ such that $f(x)=x$ is uniform continuous but both endpoint limit does not exist.

Statement: *If $f: (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous function, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ if and only if the limits
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)
$$
exist finitely.*

**Note:** Here both $a,b$ are finite.

Comment: Any comment on the above result?